# Ionic Qr Code Generator - How to use fixed value?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, qr-code

Good afternoon,

I am trying to create a card that displays a QR code from a fixed value. The plugin that I've found takes the value from an input and a button, is there any way to change the js to take the input from a fixed value?

**home.page.html**

```
<ion-card-content>
<div class="ion-padding">
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="My QR data" [(ngModel)]="qrData">
    </ion-input>


    <button ion-button full icon-left (click)="createCode()">
        <ion-icon name="barcode"></ion-icon>Create
    </button>

    <ion-card>
      <div align='center'>
        <ngx-qrcode [qrc-value]="createdCode">
        </ngx-qrcode>
      </div>
        <ion-card-content>
            <div align='center'> ID: {{ createdCode }} </div>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
```

**home.page.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  qrData = null;
  createdCode = null;
  scannedCode = null;

  constructor(private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner) {}

  createCode () {
    this.createdCode = this.qrData;
    console.log(this.createdCode);
  }

}
```

Thank you in advanced for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ionic part and the qrcode part are unrelated. Remove the input and button and simply bind a constant string to `[qrc-value]`. Notice the single quotes inside the double quotes in `[qrc-value]="'fixed value'"`. It denotes using the literal string `'fixed value'`

```
<ion-card-content>
<div class="ion-padding">
    <ion-card>
      <div align='center'>
        <ngx-qrcode [qrc-value]="'fixed value'">
        </ngx-qrcode>
      </div>
        <ion-card-content>
            <div align='center'> ID: fixed value </div>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-starter-app-b4abv9)